# Инструкция AFX_DESIGN_TIME

Tags: c++, mfc

К сожалению не нашел информации, относительно инструкции `AFX_DESIGN_TIME`. В чем принципиальное отличие, с использованием инструкции `AFX_DESIGN_TIME`:

```
class CMainDlg : public CDialog
{
public:
    CMainDlg();

#ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME
    enum { IDD = IDD_DIALOG };
#endif

};

CMainDlg::CMainDlg(IDD_DIALOG)
{
}
```

или без `AFX_DESIGN_TIME`:

```
class CMainDlg : public CDialog
{
public:
    CMainDlg();

    enum { IDD = IDD_DIALOG };

};

CMainDlg::CMainDlg(CMainDlg::IDD)
{
}
```

Спасибо

Comment: От куда вы этот макрос взяли ни МСДН, ни ГУГЛ, ни дольшой СО о нем ничего не знают?

Comment: Этот макрос создан из шаблона Wizard Application VS2015.